# Popup Image when hovering over a div (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need some help.
I want to make an image appear where the mouse is located over a div.
There is no code that I can show as I've failed many times at achieving this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From you original question and this comment ("Hello, thanks for the reply. The image needs to pop up over the div about the mouse point. Moving the mouse changes the image location to where the mouse is. Thanks though!")

I created this solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/YPu96/1/

Hover over div: The image becomes visible and follows the mouse-pointer.

On click: The image becomes invisible and stops following.

HTML:

```
<div class="someDiv">
  <p>Foobar</p>
</div>
<img style="display:none" class="image" src="http://www.budick.eu/images/logo-BudickEu.jpg"/>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".someDiv").hover(function() {
  $(document).mousemove(function(event) {
    $(".image").css({"position":"absolute","left":event.clientX ,"top":event.clientY     }).show();    
  });    
});

//end movement with click
$(document).bind("click",function(){
  $(document).unbind("mousemove");
  $(".image").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You definitely don't need to use javascript. This works on the latest version of Chrome, use vendor prefixing for transitions.

http://jsfiddle.net/pKYu2/16/

HTML

```
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    <span id="mouseOver"><img src="http://placekitten.com/120/120">Mouse Over This</span>     
</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

CSS

```
#mouseOver {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}

#mouseOver img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
    bottom: 1em;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition-duration: 800ms;    
}

#mouseOver:hover img {
    opacity: 1;
    transition-duration: 400ms;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `hover` event:

```
$("div").hover(function() {
    $("img").show();
}, function() {
    $("img").hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Appreciate it.

It needs to almost "Pop up" so it does not affect any css elements on the page. Using this method makes the img appear (not where the mouse is either) but also effects other elements.

Thanks again.

Comment: Then you need to apply CSS and configure your page - without any HTML to look at then I can't help.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/f7zJ7/

See how it pushes the texts aparts and not hover about the mouse point

Comment: Im not sure what you want to happen, but make an attempt and let me know what didnt work

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/pKYu2/2/

This will replace text

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#mouseOver').mouseover(function(e){
        $('#imageReplace').empty()
        $('#imageReplace').append("<img src=\"http://placekitten.com/120/120\" />"); 
    })
})
```

The `empty` function isn't really necessary, but I find to be good practice, as it's *very* easy to forget to unbind events from the DOM if you don't make liberal use of `.empty` and `.remove`

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply.

The image needs to pop up over the div about the mouse point. Moving the mouse changes the image location to where the mouse is.

Thanks though!